# How can I add empty new fields by clicking on a button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, react-hooks

How can I do to display a new row with empty fields `Name`, `Type`, `Email` for `Inviteds` section if I click on the `+Add new invite` ?
For now I have only the button...

```
export default function App() {
  ...    
  let handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      let res = await fetch("", {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({
          location: location,             
          ...
        })
      });
      let resJson = await res.json();
      if (res.status === 200) {
        setLocation("");
        ...
      } else {
        setMessage("Some error occured");
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col">
      ...
      <div className="mt-10 mb-3 h-6 text-md uppercase font-bold leading-8 text-gray-500">
        People
      </div>
      <button>+Add new invite</button>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <span >
          Names:
        </span>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={invitedName}
          placeholder="Names"
          onChange={(e) => setInvitedName(e.target.value)}
        />           
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here the picture to get the idea : [image]

Comment: put a checkbox input in the JSX and use the `onChange` to toggle a state (`useState`) and when it's toggled, show another section in your rendered JSX. Please tell which step in what I said should be clarified

Comment: Hi, I've changed my question

Comment: I've changed the question and was wondering if your reply can be applied to my question?  I appreciate that you take the time to reply me and sorry if you feel that I'm ignoring your question :)

Comment: Your question is still the same at its core and my question in the first comment is still standing unanswered :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The invited values should be an array of invitee objects, each with the `name`, `age`, `email`, and `location` properties. When adding a new participant add a new invitee object. Map the invited array to an array of the field inputs.

Use generated GUIDs to identify which invitee you are editing.

Example:

```
import { v4 as uuidV4 } from "uuid";

...

const [invited, setInvited] = useState([
  {
    id: uuidV4(),
    age: "",
    email: "",
    location: "",
    name: ""
  }
]);

const updateInvitee = (id) => (e) => {
  const { name, value } = e.target;
  setInvited((invitees) =>
    invitees.map((invited) =>
      invited.id === id
        ? {
            ...invited,
            [name]: value
          }
        : invited
    )
  );
};

const addInvitee = () => {
  setInvited((invitees) =>
    invitees.concat({
      id: uuidV4(),
      age: "",
      email: "",
      location: "",
      name: ""
    })
  );
};

...

<div className="mt-10 mb-3 h-6 text-md uppercase font-bold leading-8 text-gray-500">
  People
</div>
<button type="button" onClick={addInvitee}>
  +Add new participant
</button>
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
  {invited.map(({ age, email, id, location, name }) => (
    <div key={id}>
      <label className="mr-3 h-6 text-md font-bold  leading-8 text-gray-500">
        Names:
        <input
          type="text"
          value={name}
          placeholder="Names"
          name="name"
          onChange={updateInvitee(id)}
        />
      </label>
      <label className="mr-3 h-6 text-md font-bold  leading-8 text-gray-500">
        Age:
        <input
          type="text"
          value={age}
          placeholder="Age"
          name="age"
          onChange={updateInvitee(id)}
        />
      </label>
      <label className="mr-3 h-6 text-md font-bold  leading-8 text-gray-500">
        Location:
        <input
          type="text"
          value={location}
          placeholder="Location"
          name="location"
          onChange={updateInvitee(id)}
        />
      </label>
      <label className="mr-3 h-6 text-md font-bold  leading-8 text-gray-500">
        Email:
        <input
          type="text"
          value={email}
          placeholder="Email"
          name="email"
          onChange={updateInvitee(id)}
        />
      </label>
    </div>
  ))}
</form>
```

[image: Edit how-can-i-add-empty-new-fields-by-clicking-on-a-button]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! Are GUIDs unique in this case ? If I want to remove one participant, should I do the same process as well ?

Comment: @Zokulko Yes, by definition ***G***lobally ***U***nique ***Id***entifiers (GUIDs) are unique. If you want to remove one it's as trivial as `removeInvitee = id => setInvited(invitees => invitees.filter(invited => invited.id !== id))`.

Comment: Yes this is what I have done too:   `const removeInvitees = (id) => {
    setInvited((invitees) => invitees.filter((invited) => invited.id !== id));
  };` and use it here  `<button type="button" onClick={removeInvitees}>
        +Remove invitee</button>` but it removes nothing ([code](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-banach-y0q42s?)

Comment: @Zokulko The button isn't passing an id to the callback, but instead the callback is receiving the `onClick` event object. Try something like `onClick={() => removeInvitees(id)}`. I've updated the sandbox.

Comment: Yeah I've finally managed to do it :)  but for some reason I can't type in my textboxes...

Comment: @Zokulko Did you convert the `value` props to the mapped invitee's properties?

Comment: I've finally managed to work it btw thank man :)

Comment: Hi, I've opened a new [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72398235/react-default-value-with-react-select-checkboxes-not-working-after-axios-post-d), where I'm using axios.post please ?